# Displaying the number of items, similar to a shopping cart

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, shopping-cart

I'm looking to display a number similar to a shopping cart. I was given the php code and it currently displays a cookie value and it kind of works accept if you click add to cart and there are errors in what you've typed it will add 1 to the cookie but wont add anything to the cart.

I tried using AngularJS to display the length of a sessions variable which worked a little better but it doesn't update until you refresh the page.

Could anyone point me in the right direction so I can try and figure this out for myself.

This is the code that I was orginally given:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['count']))
{
    $cookie = 0;
    setcookie("count", $cookie);
}
else
{

    if (isset($_GET["add"]))
        {
        $cookie = ++$_COOKIE['count'];
        setcookie("count",$cookie);
        }
    else if (isset($_GET["remove"]))
        {
        $cookie = --$_COOKIE['count'];
        setcookie("count", $cookie);
        }
    else {
        $cookie = $_COOKIE['count'];
        setcookie("count", $cookie);
        }

    $cookie = $_COOKIE['count'];

    if ($cookie <= 0)
    {
        $cookie = 0;
        setcookie("count", $cookie);
    }
}
```

It's then printed like this

```
<li><a><div ng-app="" class="circle"> <?php echo $cookie ?></div></a></li>
```

I tried chaging the echo $cookie to echo the session array length and also tried using

```
<li><a><div ng-app="" class="circle">{{ <?php echo count($_SESSION['certificates']) ?>}}</div></a></li>
```

I also tried this link: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mMwVPb

but didn't quite understand it all and couldn't get it working on my page.

It almost works the way I want it to but I just have to refresh the page to display the session array length. If there's a way to display the value of the session without having to refresh the page I think that would fix it.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: Impossible to help you since you did not provide any code.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I would not mess with a cookie unless you maybe want to persist the cart when the user leaves your site with items left in the cart then comes back to your store. At that point you can store the cart items in a database or something with a reference id to the cookie or something. People can turn off cookies, so you are SOL if your cart depends on cookies and the user turns them off.

I would store your cart in the session since you can store arrays easily in a session:

```
# Simple example of add to cart function
addToCart($sku,$qty=1)
    {
        # Make sure the quantity is a number
        if(!is_numeric($qty))
            $qty = 1;
        # If the cart is not yet set, create it
        if(!isset($_SESSION['cart']))
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
        # If the item is already in the cart, increment the quantity
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart'][$sku]))
            $_SESSION['cart'][$sku] += $qty;
        # If not in the cart already, create it
        else
            $_SESSION['cart'][$sku] = $qty;
    }

# Remember to start session on every page
session_start();

# To add to cart
if(isset($_REQUEST['add'])) {
    # Insert the sku in param 1, quantity into param 2
    addToCart($_REQUEST['ITEMCODE'],$_REQUEST['QTY']);
}
# Set some storage variables
$totalQty = 
$itemsQty = 0;
# To get qty in cart
if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    # Loop through items in cart
    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $sku => $qty) {
        $totalQty += $qty;
        $itemsQty += 1;
    }
}
?>
<!-- If you have 5 products in the cart, this will say 5 -->
<h2>Total products in cart: <?php echo $itemsQty ?></h2>
<!-- If you have 5 products with quantity of 2 per product, this will write 10 -->
<h2>Total items in cart: <?php echo $totalQty ?></h2>
```

Comment: So I've used sessions for this and it almost works the way I want it. The cart number is displayed in the header and is always 1 behind the actual number so it will display 1 if the is 2 items

Comment: If you add an item to cart, and it doesn't register until you refresh the page, you just do a header redirect after you add ti cart,